# Trying to test FormControlLabel in enzyme won't trigger click when simulate

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to test a FormControlLabel component from material UI.
When I try to simulate click Enzyme won't fire a click event on my component.

I tried using shallow, createShallow, mount, createMount.

In debug I get the component from the find and findWhere query and by the looks of it it has a props of control that contains the wanted checkbox.

I also tried to wrap the checkbox from the retrieved props with shallow and mount and it didn't work...

```js
//parent.jsx
export public Parent = () => {
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
const handleChange = (e,s) => {setSelected(s);};
...
return (
...
    <FormControlLabel control={
        <Checkbox onChange={handleChange} 
                checked={selected}}
label='some label'/>
...
);
}


//test.js
...
let component = createMount()(<Parent/>);

let checkbox = component.find(FormControlLabel)
.findWhere(c=>c.prop('label')==='some label').first();

checkbox.simulate('click');
checkbox.simulate('change');

//rest of the test
//the function handleChange is not called in debug.
```

Expected:

- simulate click or change should call the onChange function

Actual:

- change won't be triggered

the code works, the test dont.

please help!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
let checkbox = component.find(FormControlLabel);
checkbox.prop('control').props.onChange({ target: { checked: true }, persist: jest.fn() });
```

Worked for me using shallow.

Comment: Also if the control prop has multiple components wrapped in fragment then needs to be find the props like this: .props.children[0].props etc...

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to construct an event that has a `checked : true` field.

modifying your code:

```
let checkbox = component.find(FormControlLabel).findWhere(c=>c.prop('label')==='some label').first();
// Wrap the control prop.
enzyme.shallow(checkbox.prop('control')).simulate('change', { target : { checked : true }} );
```